# Handle multiple enemies firing bullets at the same time

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to make all my enemies simultaneously shoot bullets at the player. My code works for one enemy shooting at a time, but what I'm trying to do is to make them all fire simultaneously.

For brevity's sake I'm using this simple condition to trigger the `fire_bullets` function : `if (player.x > thisEnemy.x) { //fire bullets`. What I intended to do is, the farther the player moves to the right, the more enemies start shooting bullets. Problem is the condition is only working for the first enemy in the array, while the other ones simply won't fire any bullet. You can see demo here :

https://jsfiddle.net/Lau1989/796xr7vg/

Here is my `fire_bullets()` function :

```
function fire_bullets(thisEnemy) {
  var HTMLbullets = document.querySelectorAll('.HTMLbullets');
  for (var b = 0; b < HTMLbullets.length; b++) {
    var time = new Date().getTime()/1000 - startTime; 
    if (bullets[b].isOut && time > 0.5) {
      if (player.x > thisEnemy.x) {
        bullets[b] = bullets_pool(thisEnemy.x, thisEnemy.y);
      }
      startTime = new Date().getTime()/1000;
    }
    if (!bullets[b].isOut) {
      bullets[b].y -= 4;

      if (bullets[b].y <= 50) { //check if bullet is out of range and recycle it
        bullets[b].isOut = true; 
        var thisBullet = bullets.splice(b, 1)[b];
        thisBullet.x = -100;
        bullets.push(thisBullet);
      }
    }
    HTMLbullets[b].style.left = bullets[b].x +"px";
    HTMLbullets[b].style.top = bullets[b].y +"px";
  }
}
```

My latest try was to add the `fire_bullets` function as a property to each enemy object and then call it whenever their x position is lower than the player x position, but it only made the last enemy being triggered to fire its bullets, while the other ones stopped shooting theirs.

How should I proceed to make all my enemies simultaneously fire bullets at the player ? Is there a good performance-wise solution to do it, considering that each level frequently has dozens of enemies firing bullets at the same time ?

Comment: You may want to consider an event listener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thank you for your answer : I used keyup and keydown event listeners but I still can't get more than one enemy firing bullets at a time.

Comment: where are you calling fire_bullets function, you are passing thisEnemy to this, so it will work for only thisEnemy(only one). You have to call fire_bullets function for each enemy.

Comment: Thank you Manoj : I just double checked my `game_loop()` function and I actually passed every enemy (via the for loop) as an argument to the `fire_bullets()` function ;  so `thisEnemy` should normally refer to each element of the enemie's array... Or am I mistaking ? See this part : `for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {fire_bullets(enemies[i]);}`